# How is async task managed in the background in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

How does android manages the async tasks as in how are the threads managed in the background and how can i manage threads so that they follow a queue type pattern of execution in android.

Comment: It will use onPreExecute,dodoInBackground and onPostExecute by defualt to manage the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AsyncTask` uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` combined with a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, so basically it will do what you want, I think. See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask) for more info.

Comment: yes its true i think Post Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB it will manage a single process queue